# Yellow goo on ISP's WiFi equipment?

Tags: cat5e

I am seeing a yellow like goo in my ISP's outdoor cabinets for my WiMax network.

The cat5 runs up the building to a BSR and then to the antennas. Am I losing power and signal quality from this, and what causes this goo?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. What are the details of the equipment you're using? Also, I don't think anyone will be able to identify a mysterious yellow goo without at least being able to see it. Do you have any pictures you can share?

Comment: Why would you not just report this to your ISP ?

Comment: lain: Why take the most direct and sensible route when you can post your question to the internet instead?

Answer (score 2):

This is kinda funny, but it's probably the result of water causing chemical run off from treated paper or wood used in cheap cabinets and air conditioners and dehumidifers.  Really.  [The best online reference I could Google real quick is the review linked here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16896124016&SortField=0&SummaryType=0&PageSize=10&SelectedRating=-1&VideoOnlyMark=False&IsFeedbackTab=true#scrollFullInfo).

> The evaporator is a treated paper filter. The chemical used to treat
>   the paper comes off in the continuously circulating water in the form
>   of an accumulating yellow goo. I, daily, cleaned the water "trickling"
>   tray as the drip-orifices would clog. Over 6 months the tubes to and
>   from the pump clogged with the goo. It's now just a low-noise fan.